# How do I add array values together until they reach a specific number then create objects with the added values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with 5 different values for width and a max width of 6 that needs to be reached. How would I go about iterating through the array and building an object with those values each time it hits the max value without going over?

Consider:

```
var max_width = "6";
var max_height = "200";
var widths = [{
        sku: "CSUT3",
        width: 3,
        height: 11
    }, {
        sku: "TUS45",
        width: 2.5,
        height: 4
    }, {
        sku: "TUS54",
        width: 6,
        height: 4
    }, {
        sku: "SRT55",
        width: 3.5,
        height: 4
    }, {
        sku: "RTS3",
        width: 3.75,
        height: 4
}];
```

Using the data in the widths array, how would I create the for loop to add the widths together and create the array below:

```
var columns = [
    {
      skus: ["CSUT3", "TUS45"], 
      widths: [3, 2.5], 
      heights: [11, 4]
    },
    {
      skus: ["TUS54"], 
      widths: [6], 
      heights: [4]
    },
    {
      skus: ["SRT55"], 
      widths: [3.5], 
      heights: [4]
    },
    {
      skus: ["RTS3"], 
      widths: [3.75], 
      heights: [4]
    }
];
```

I can loop through the widths like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
    alert(widths[i].width)
}
```

But how would I get the iterations to add together until reaching the max_width value and create an object to push to the columns array once the condition has been met?

Comment: do you have some other constraints as well, like to minimize elements or try to get close to the wanted max value? should the order be maintained?

Comment: @NinaScholz The constraint is to never go beyond the max value, the order does not matter as long as the widths combined or singular are less than or equal to the max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` method here.

```js
var max_width = "6";
var max_height = "200";
var widths = [{
  sku: "CSUT3",
  width: 3,
  height: 11
}, {
  sku: "TUS45",
  width: 2.5,
  height: 4
}, {
  sku: "TUS54",
  width: 6,
  height: 4
}, {
  sku: "SRT55",
  width: 3.5,
  height: 4
}, {
  sku: "RTS3",
  width: 3.75,
  height: 4
}];

const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)

const res = widths.reduce((arr, {
  sku,
  width,
  height
}) => {
  if (!arr.length ||
    sum(arr[arr.length - 1].width) + width > max_width ||
    sum(arr[arr.length - 1].height) + height > max_height) {
    arr.push({
      sku: [sku],
      width: [width],
      height: [height]
    })
  } else {
    arr[arr.length - 1].width.push(width);
    arr[arr.length - 1].height.push(height);
    arr[arr.length - 1].sku.push(sku);
  }
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

**FYI:** This solution only compares adjacent values in the array.